# Admob custom event Intererstitial doesn't work

Tags: android, ios, admob, chartboost

I have been trying to implement the admob custom event for Chartboost interstitial ads but the custom event never fires.

I my add custom event settings page on admob I set my Class Name to **com.mycompany.advertising.ChartBoostInterstitial**

The file is located in this package, src folder/com.mycompany.advertising.ChartBoostInterstitial

Here is the class,

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.chartboost.sdk.CBLocation;
import com.chartboost.sdk.Chartboost;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.MediationAdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.customevent.CustomEventInterstitial;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.customevent.CustomEventInterstitialListener;

public class ChartBoostInterstitial implements CustomEventInterstitial {


    public static CustomEventInterstitialListener mListener;

    @Override
    public void requestInterstitialAd(Context context,
            CustomEventInterstitialListener listener, String serverParameter,
            MediationAdRequest mediationAdRequest, Bundle customEventExtras) {
        System.out.println("GOOGLE MEDIATION CALLING THIS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");

            mListener = listener;
            Chartboost.cacheInterstitial(CBLocation.LOCATION_DEFAULT);

    }

    @Override
    public void showInterstitial() {
        Chartboost.showInterstitial(CBLocation.LOCATION_DEFAULT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

The manual is not clear on if this class is supposed to be instantiated or not. The System.out.println("GOOGLE MEDIATION CALLING THIS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"); is never called no matter how many ads I load. If I can get at least this line to print then I should be able to build up the rest of the custom event adapter. The only thing that happens is that a normal adMob interstitial loads.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the correct path of your class like
com.packagename.classname in the newly created customevent in admob

in admob u cant expect the changes to be taken place immedietly.. it tooks more than an hour to gets reflected..

happy coding